# SQL : can i use null at OR

Tags: mysql, sql

can i use statement NULL at OR like this ?

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Status='0' OR Status='3' OR Status IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes you can use

Comment: Slightly simplified `where Status in ('0', '3') OR Status IS NULL`

Comment: Have you tested it yourself? I don't really understand why you need to ask this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `IN` for all but the `NULL` value:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Status IN (0, 3) OR Status IS NULL;
```

As Zaynul points out, don't use single quotes for numeric constants.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Answer (score 0):

for integer value no need single quote and yes you can filter all three or more

```
 SELECT * FROM Table 
 WHERE Status=0 OR Status=3 OR Status IS NULL
```

Comment: How do you know that the status column is an integer?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way is to assume that 0 is a default value for null statuses, and use:

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE COALESCE(Status, 0) IN (0, 3)`